# PHP $_GET variables rearrange in URL, Why?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I go to:

```
https://sitedomain/product-name-p-1106.html?ref=facebook&keyw=pagetype0:friends
```

The url changes to:

```
https://sitedomain/product-name-p-1106.html?keyw=pagetype0friends&ref=facebook
```

Basicly the *$ref* and *$keyw* variables reverse. **Why is this happening and how can I stop it?**

Note: I am trying to use a script that relies on them being in the order $ref then $keyw that someone else wrote and I would like to keep them in that order to not modify that script.

I think it might be the .htaccess file but not sure, here is the file for that:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-t-([0-9_]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-au-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-links-([0-9_]+).html$ links.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-n-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nc-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nri-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nra-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why does it matter? The ordering shouldn't matter. Note that your `.htaccess` isn't just reordering, you're also losing the colon in `pagetype0:friends`.

Comment: does it matter what order the variables are in?

Comment: does .htaccess sort them by name?

Comment: I am trying to use a script someone else wrote that relies on them being in that order, trying to not modify that script.

Comment: No PHP script that is accessing these variables via `$_GET` requires them in a specific order. So if you're referring to `product_info.php` that requires this order, something is wrong with the script, not the URL.

Comment: I access them via get in another script and thats fine, but in the script that has the problem the url is broken down with strpos and substr, should I retitle this question? I just want to know why they reverse and how can I stop it....

Comment: @nickb where is the .htaccess reordering?

Answer (score 2):

They are just named parameters and don't need any specific order. If you are relying on any specific ordering, you are doing something fundamentally wrong in your code.

Comment: Didn't write the code that relies on it being in that order and I hope to not have to change it... For what I am trying to work with they do need to be in that specific order...

Comment: If a script relies on parameter order, you should really wonder what else it does wrong.

Comment: If the order matters, then just reverse the code which deals with them. Problem solved.

Comment: @itachi true, do you see anycode in the .htaccess responsible for the ordering?

Comment: I won't gonna go through all those codes. The best i can offer is, why order is so important? Because i never heard the order to be that important.

Answer (score 0):

The message I am getting here is:

Don't ever make or use code that depends on the order of URL parameters

Answer (score 0):

$_GET vars shouldn't be dependent on the order unless you're foreaching $_GET and blatantly ignoring indexes. Also, MOD_REWRITE doesn't re-order things in the URI on the browser side but only changes the order/assignment server-side.

As others have said, something is very wrong if the order is that important and in which case I'd pass the value as a delimited string as opposed to individual $_GET values.

I know you "don't want" to rewrite this script, but as someone else said think of what else it might be doing wrong? Further, do you really want a point of failure like this?